# What are L and D in r-w-x-l-d segment flags of IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

I tried to google this for a while but I don’t think I’ve phrased it correctly.

```
R read
W write
X execute
L ?
D ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The D stands for debugger only and L for created by the loader - see [IDA documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/525.shtml)